# Finish method of batch class is not invoked when error occurs

Tags: batch, callout

I have a batch class that http callout in the start method. Also, wrote an some block of codes to send notification when something went wrong in the finish method. 
However, when api return unsuccessful response, batch class doesn't invoke the finished method. So, I don't get exception notification email. Also, I tried to add try-catch structure to inside of start method to get notification, instead of this, I don't get email still. In the debug log, I can see email subject etc. but it doesn't send. How should I proceed? 
Btw, email deliverability is open.

```
public class LibringGetDailySpentBatchable implements Database.Batchable<LibringIntegrationJsonParser.Connections>, Database.allowscallouts, Database.Stateful{

public String nextPage;
public Decimal cPage;
public Decimal tPage;
public String network;

public LibringGetDailySpentBatchable(String nextBatchUrl, String network){
    nextPage = nextBatchUrl;
    this.network = network;
}

public LibringGetDailySpentBatchable(String network){
    this.network = network;
}

public Iterable<LibringIntegrationJsonParser.Connections> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    LibringIntegration.Result r = new LibringIntegration.Result();

    //Callout
    if(nextPage == null){
        r = LibringIntegration.getAllThisMonth(null,network);
    }
    else{
        r = LibringIntegration.getAllThisMonth(nextPage,null);
    }

    //Parsing
    LibringIntegrationJsonParser rs = LibringIntegrationJsonParser.parse(r.body);

    nextPage = rs.next_page_url;
    cPage = rs.current_page;
    tPage = rs.total_pages;

    return rs.connections;
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<LibringIntegrationJsonParser.Connections> allData){

    Some codes
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {


    AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, ExtendedStatus
                      FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =
                      :info.getJobId()];


    if(a.NumberOfErrors > 0 ||test.isRunningTest()){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] sendingTo = Label.Error_Message_Contacts.split(',');
        semail.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
        semail.setSubject('Libring Integration Failed');
        semail.setPlainTextBody('Libring integration failed. It is called again'+ a.ExtendedStatus);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {semail});


    }



}
```

}

Comment: The `finish` method only runs at the very end of all the batches that run, not at the end of a single batch

Comment: What can you suggest for notifying?

Comment: Instead of handling this in the `finish` method, use a `try catch` block within the `start` and/or `execute` methods, and put that email sending code in a catch block

Comment: That doesn't work. Either I tried it and mentioned about that idea above

Comment: How do you know if the API callout was unsuccessful?  I'm assuming it's packed into the `LibringIntegration.Result r` and parsing out the `r.body`?  Maybe do checks there on the API callout and send emails as needed at that point in the code.  `try catch` block isn't necessarily going to detect API callout failures

Comment: I know because request throw read timeout exception

Answer (score 3):

With your goal being error handling in batch jobs, let me introduce you to the Winter '19 `BatchApexErrorEvent`!

<strike>It slices, it dices...</strike> It provides a mechanism to raise platform events from a batch job. More importantly, it is specifically designed for your error handling scenario.

The majority of details you need are covered in [Building a Batch Retry Framework With BatchApexErrorEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/01/building-a-batch-retry-framework-with-batchapexerrorevent.html).

The short version is that you mark you batch job as implementing the `Database.RaisesPlatformEvents` interface. Then it will start sending out Platform events as the Batch Job runs. Then you subscribe to the `BatchApexErrorEvent` events and handle them as required.

[image]